# angular 2 performance issue in IE

Tags: angular

My angular 2  application drop downs responds well in chrome but it is very slow in IE.I switched to prod mode and i used core-js instead of es6-shim.js but still IE drop down were too slow.Please help me how can I improve performace of angular 2 drop down in IE.

Comment: Which version of IE you talking about?

Comment: Almost the version, Could you precise if low performances are on loading the application or on user interactions ?

Comment: IE 11. I am using ui-select drop downs.(Drop down along with the search filter).It is taking very much time to load in IE but in chrome its fast enough.

Comment: The delay is on user interaction when user types some thing in a dropDown with custom search filter.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue and after throwing everything I could think of at it I've come to the conclusion that IE just doesn't want to handle updating filters when using selects.

My solution is to change your selects to look like this:

```
<select class="selectList" ng-model="selectedIds[$index]"  ng-options="sample.id as sample.value for sample in samples | myfilter:selectedIds:$index" data-ng-change="fixIE()"></select>
```

They now have a class and an ng-change on them. Then in your controller do this fun little bit of code:

```
$scope.fixIE = function(){
    //here write code to check if IE so the other browsers don't get this ugly hack.
    var selectLists = document.querySelectorAll(".selectList");
    for(var x = 0;x  < selectLists.length; x++){
        selectLists[x].parentNode.insertBefore(selectLists[x], selectLists[x]);
    }       
};
```

Same you can do in angular2, hope this helps. Just give a try. Something similar to this..

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <select [ngModel]="selectedIds[$index]" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
      <option *ngFor="#sample of samples">{{sample}}</option>
    </select>
  `)
  export class SomeComponent {

    onChange(newValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
      // ... do other stuff here ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry.The solution doesn't works for me.Please suggest me alternative solution.

Comment: if you were using angular1.x, I would have given you my directive code for it, you can give a try to this - `var selectPicker = $timeout(function() {
                    $(element).find('.bs-select').selectpicker({
                        iconBase: 'fa',
                        tickIcon: 'fa-check'
                    });
                    $(element).find('.bs-select').selectpicker('render');
                    $(element).find('.bs-select').selectpicker('val', listOfItems);
                    $(element).find('.bs-select').selectpicker('refresh');
                }, 0);`

Comment: I am using Angular 2.I am not getting how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** This is not a permanent fix, but you can do something like create a ng:if where disabled the angular ui-select if the object is empty (e.g. no options selected). So for the directive to render a user must press on a button and then the UI renders. This prevents about 80% of the ui-selects from rendering on page.

Here is some sample code

```
<ui-select ng:if="user.hasExtensions"
///
</ui-select>   
<span ng:if="!user.hasExtensions"
      ng:click="user.hasExtensions = true; refreshPlaceholder();"
      class="btn-info-callinize">
   <i class='icon-plus-sign icon-white'</i>
</span>
```

**2)** Other hack with this is if your listOfItems is too big.. you can use `| limitTo: 100`

**3)** To activate the dropdown select choice only after x letter are typed :

```
<ui-select-choices refresh="checkList($select.search)" refresh-delay="400" repeat="item.id as item in listOfItems | filter: {list: $select.search} | limitTo: limitlistsearch">
```

In controller

$scope.limitlistsearch = 100; //Init with no limit: to see a previous selected value

```
    $scope.checkList = function (stringTyped) {
        if (stringTyped.length >= 2) {
            $scope.limitlistsearch = 50;
        }
        else {
          $scope.limitlistsearch = 0;
        }
    }
```

4) Refer to this link (might helps) https://github.com/inetsys/ng-formalizer/commit/e18630297a50efaf0bb629cb26cfc6eea1d841d5

**5)** Switch to another component https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize

Disadvantage is that it is a wrapper to a Jquery based component, and does not offer all the themes options.

Advantages are - the directive is very very small, the configuration is mostly not in the HTML but in the controller, so the HTML is much easier to read, configure and REUSE. It also does not inherit Angular performance problems.